# center manifold and bifurcation: 2D Bifurcation system reduction

Tags: manifolds, dynamical-systems, bifurcation, linearization, set-invariance

I have this system to study
$$
\left\{ 
\begin{aligned} 
\frac{dx}{dt} &= y-x - x^2 \\[5pt]
\frac{dy}{dt} &= \mu x - y - y^2
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$

I have derived the Jacobian around fixed point
$$
\phi = (0, 0). 
$$

I have found eigenvalues
$$
\lambda_{\pm} = \pm \sqrt{\mu} - 1
$$
and eigenvectors
$$
f_{\pm} = (\pm 1,1)
$$
in the case of
$$
\mu = \mu_c = 1. 
$$

I compute the system in order to write it in term of $c_+$, $c_-$ which are in the base of
$$
f_{\pm} = (\pm 1, 1). 
$$
I got
$$
\left\{ 
\begin{aligned} 
\frac{dc_-}{dt} &= -2 c_- - (c_+ + c_-)^2 \\[5pt] 
\frac{dc_+}{dt} &= -c_+^2 - c_-^2 
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$

Now, my problems begin:
In the neighborhood of $\mu_c$, at the dominant order of $\epsilon = \mu -\mu_c$, I must reduce the system made of $c_+$ and $c_-$ to one dimension.
I don't know how to start and where to go, my lectures on center manifold don't help me. If someone has an idea.

Regards

Xav